# use multiple go routines for different operations on mysql

Tags: mysql, go

I have a piece of Go code with 3 different functions, insertIntoMysql, updateRowMysql and deleteRowmysql. I check for operation type and run one of these functions as needed.

I want to convert my normal functions into go routines to be able to handle more operations.

But here is the issue:
If I convert into goroutines, I will lose the sequence of operations.

For example, the insert operations are much more frequent than the delete operations and insert operations are being queued in the insert channel while the delete channel is empty it is possible for my code to try to delete a row before it gets inserted (e.g. a row is inserted and the deleted 1 sec later).

Any ideas on how to make sure the sequence of my operations on mysql is the same as the received operations.

here is the code:

```
    go insertIntoMysql(insertChan, fields, db, config.DestinationTable)
    go updatefieldMysql(updateChan, fields, db, config.DestinationTable)
    go deleteFromMysql(deleteChan, fields, db, config.DestinationTable)


    for !opsDone {
        select {
        case op, open := <-mysqlChan:
            if !open {
                opsDone = true
                break
            }

            switch op.Operation {
            case "i":
                //fmt.Println("got insert operation")
                insertChan <- op
                break
            case "u":
                fmt.Println("got update operation")
                updateChan <- op
                break
            case "d":
                fmt.Println("got delete operation")
                deleteChan <- op
                break
            case "c":
                fmt.Println("got command operation")
                //no logic yet
                break
            }

            break
        }
    }
    close(done)
    close(insertChan)
    close(deleteChan)
    close(updateChan)

}
```

Comment: "I want to convert my normal functions into go routines" This is a logical impossibility. goroutines and functions are categorically distinct. A function is a unit of code to be executed.  A goroutine is a scheduling concept. Goroutines run functions. Functions cannot "become" goroutines.

Comment: Beyond that, it's impossible to offer a suggestion without seeing the actual code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code and your question/requirement: Stay in order as the original go channel delivered the data.
Staying in sync and still firing off multiple go routines to process the data, could be done like this:

```
func processStatements(mysqlChan chan *instructions) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    prevOp := "" // Previous operation
    for {
        op, open := <-mysqlChan
        if !open {
            break
        }
        if prevOp!=op.Operation {
            // Next operation type, unknown side effects on previous operations, 
            // wait for previous to finish before continuing
            wg.Wait()
        }

        switch op.Operation {
        case "i":
            wg.Add(1)
            go processInsert(op,wg)
            break
        case "u":
            wg.Add(1)
            go processUpdate(op,wg)
            break
        case "d":
            wg.Add(1)
            go processDelete(op,wg)
            break
        case "c":
            break
        }
        prevOp = op.Operation
    }
    // Previous go routines might still be running, wait till done
    wg.Wait()
    // Close any channels
}

func processInsert(c chan *sqlCall,wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // Do actual insert etc
}
```

The main differences with your program are:

- Processing is in order, safe against your base scenario
- Process of next operation type will wait until previous operation type is finished
- Multiple of the same operations run in parallel (as for in your code a single operation per type would run in parallel). Depending on the data distribution either of them can be faster or slower (i,i,i,d,u = 3 waits in this code, while it would also be 3 waits in your code, however in your code the 3 i would run sequential, here they run parallel) (Look into insert or update for mysql, since now your inserts could suddenly be updates depending on your data).

Comment: routines for create, update and delete operations are separate and have separate channels as well

Comment: you logic is sound however i have one question:
on a busy database assuming 1000 inserts come sequentially would it be best to spawn all these go routines this rapidly?

Comment: It really depends on the database throughput and settings: You might want a connection pool to start with (you don't want to make 5k connections to pretty much any database). The database in the end will execute sequentially per page where smaller page settings can help in throughput (but also in overhead as the number of records per page will be lower). What you will win with many go routines is a reduction in the network wait. You can also limit how many routines you might want to start to prevent OOM (and loosing your transactions)

Answer (score 0):

How would the one that calls `delete` know about the row in the first place? From a SQL perspective: if it is not committed, it does not exist. Something calls your code to `insert`. Your code should return only after the transaction is completed. At which point the caller could start `select`, `update` or `delete`.

For example, in a web server: Only the client that called `insert` knows of the existence to the record initially. Other clients will only learn of its existence after running `select`. That `select` will only return the new record if it was committed in the transaction that `insert`ed it. Now they might decide to `upsert` or `delete`.

Many SQL databases take care of proper [row locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html), which will ensure data integrity during concurrent access. So if you use Go routines to write to the same record, they will become sequential (in any given order) on the DB side. Concurrent reads could still happen.

Please note that `net/http` already runs a Go routine for every request. And so do most other server front-ends for Go. If you are writing something different altogether, like a custom TCP listener, you could initiate your own Go routine for each request.

Comment: my code assumes that operation received is correct however i need to keep the order of operations while working with mysql while doing it with different go routines

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand the problem, the following can be done as a resolution :

1. Call Insert, Delete or Update as go routines and they will run concurrently and performing all these operations.
2. Ensure you have row-level locking in your MySQL DB (I am sure InnoDb provides that)
3. For your delete and update operations, have an isExist check to check if the row you are updating/deleting exists before deleting and updating the row, this allows for some level of control.
4. You can implement a retry mechanism in your channel (with jitter preferably) to ensure that even if Delete Operation goes before insert operation, it will fail the exist check and then can be retried(after a second or 0.5 second or some config) and this will ensure insert record is already performed before delete or update operation is retried.

Hope this helps.

Comment: will try these tnx

Comment: Any feedback for why this answer was downvoted ?
I think this answer will work and I can provide a complete solution (had the question asked for the same)